# Installing SQL Server 2019 Analysis Services on a SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-mining

I noticed that in SQL Server 2022, SSAS' Data Mining is discontinued as per this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/data-mining/data-mining-wizard-analysis-services-data-mining?view=asallproducts-allversions

However, I'd like to utilise this datamining feature on my multi-dimensional project that is using SQL Server 2022. I was wondering if there is a way to install SSAS 2019 onto a SQL Server 2022 so I can use this discontinued feature?